# Errors running a TZScan instance

Tags: tzscan

I'm trying to run a local instance of tzscan:
https://gitlab.com/tzscan/tzscan
But I'm not 100% sure about how to fix the following errors:

```
Error log:
Error:
[644.1] 

File "./libs/ez-api/libs/ez-api/ezEncodingJS.ml", line 80, characters 26-32:
Error: Unbound module Js

Error:
rule 644: target ./_obuild/ez-api-js/ezEncodingJS.cmo not built
Error:
[625.1]

File "./libs/base58-blockies/base58Blockies.ml", line 82, characters 7-32:
Error (warning 3): deprecated: module Tyxml_js
Will be removed past 2019-04-01. Use Js_of_ocaml_tyxml.Tyxml_js instead.

Error:
rule 625: target ./_obuild/base58-blockies/base58Blockies.cmi not built
Error:
rule 625: target ./_obuild/base58-blockies/base58Blockies.cmo not built
Makefile:44: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

Is there anyone that can help, or is there more info I need to post to be able to?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to the dependency `js_of_ocaml`. Some backward incompatibilities have been introduced in the API of the last versions (`3.3.0` and `3.4.0`).

Try to manually downgrade by doing `opam install js_of_ocaml.3.2.0 js_of_ocaml-compiler.3.2.0 js_of_ocaml-lwt.3.2.0 js_of_ocaml-tyxml.3.2.0 js_of_ocaml-ppx.3.2.0`, "clean up" everything and retry to build...

Answer (score 0):

No unfortunately the last release on http://gitlab.com/tzscan/tzscan is only compatible with js_of_ocaml.3.4.0, it will not work with 3.3.0 or 3.2.0.
So there must a problem in your switch. Could you provide us with the result of `opam list`?